# How do I find PostgreSQL's data directory?

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

I forgot how I started PostgreSQL the last time (it was months ago) and I don't remember where the data directory is located. The `postgres` command seems to require the location of the data directory.

I'm on MacOsX if that helps.

`/usr/local/postgres` doesn't exist on my Mac.

Using the answers provided below, I found that it was here:

```
/usr/local/var/postgres
```

Comment: in many cases it is sufficient to switch to the postgres user `sudo su - postgres` and check the home directory path using `pwd`.

Comment: Use `SELECT current_setting('data_directory') AS pgdata_path;`

Answer (score 242):

If you can connect to the database with superuser access, then

```
SHOW data_directory;
```

is the shortest way.

If the server is not running and you forgot where the data directory was, then you really have to guess yourself.  An operating system specific convention or the shell history might provide hints.

Comment: if it's not running, try running a find for postgresql.conf, which is usually in the data directory, or will have information about the data directory.

Answer (score 48):

You can also query for it

```
select setting from pg_settings where name = 'data_directory';
```

Comment: Returned 0 rows for pgsql v.10

Answer (score 41):

`pg_config` shows a lot of information including the data directory:

```
CONFIGURE = '--disable-debug' '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.2' 
            '--datadir=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.2/share/postgresql' 
            '--docdir=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.2/share/doc/postgresql' 
            '--enable-thread-safety' '--with-bonjour' '--with-gssapi' '--with-krb5' 
            '--with-ldap' '--with-openssl' '--with-pam' '--with-libxml' '--with-libxslt'
            '--with-ossp-uuid' '--with-python' '--with-perl' '--with-tcl' 'CC=clang' 
            'CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/Cellar/ossp-uuid/1.6.2/include' 
            'LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/ossp-uuid/1.6.2/lib' 'LIBS=-luuid'
```

This might be a brew-specific thing, though; without brew I don't know what it shows.

Comment: I'm using brew too.  As of now, the datadir listed in `pg_config --configure` is not the same as the one `brew info postgresql` recommends (which is `$(brew --prefix)/var/postgres` and is not a symlink to the one listed). It seems the formula is a bit lax on using config flags properly.

Comment: Note for Ubuntu/Debain: pg_config is not installed with the `postgresql-<ver>` apt package, but requires also `postgresql-server-dev-<ver>`

Comment: @PSCL True, but OP was under OS X.

Answer (score 26):

On Ubuntu\Debian, try the `pg_lsclusters` command.

On my machine:

```
pg_lsclusters 
Version Cluster   Port Status Owner    Data directory             Log file
8.4     main      5432 online postgres /home/adam/db/main/data    /home/adam/db/main/log
```

Answer (score 12):

If you can't log in (eg, forgot your password) but the service is running, as MacOS X is a posix varient, you can always check `ps` to see if it's being passed in as an argument :

On a linux box with two postgres instances running:

```
-bash-3.2$ ps ax | grep postgres | grep -v postgres:
 4698 ?        S      9:59 /opt/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/postgres -D /opt/PostgreSQL/8.4/data
 6115 ?        S      8:16 /opt/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/postgres -D /opt/PostgreSQL/8.4/data_sums
30694 pts/9    S+     0:00 grep postgres
```

Answer (score 9):

Modern versions of the PostgreSQL desktop client for OSX have a convenient "Server Settings" dialog that will allow you not just to list the data directory but open it directly.

Very useful if you experience a random machine crash that leaves behind a lock file.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Open postgresql.conf, go to the line:

```
data_directory='/var/lib/postgresql/main/'
```

is your answer.

Comment: This line is commented out in my PostgreSQL.conf.

Answer (score 4):

Generalizing from the 2 top answers:

To show the data directory directly at the command-line:

```
psql -U postgres -tA -c "SHOW data_directory;"
```

To also see all other defined paths to files and directories:

```
psql -U postgres -c "SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE setting LIKE '/%';"
```

Sample output:

```
          name           |                 setting                  
-------------------------+------------------------------------------
 config_file             | /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
 data_directory          | /mnt/pg_ssd_500/9.6/main
 external_pid_file       | /var/run/postgresql/9.6-main.pid
 hba_file                | /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf
 ident_file              | /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_ident.conf
 ssl_cert_file           | /etc/ssl/pg_server.cer
 ssl_key_file            | /etc/ssl/private/pg_server.key
 stats_temp_directory    | /var/run/postgresql/9.6-main.pg_stat_tmp
 unix_socket_directories | /var/run/postgresql
(9 rows)
```

(On Windows, replace `LIKE '/%'` with `LIKE '%/%'` because the path starts with a drive letter)

See also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html which gives more details.

For example:

> For each database in the cluster there is a subdirectory within PGDATA/base, named after the database's OID in pg_database

So this will give the specific data directories under `$PGDATA/base` for each database:

```
psql -U postgres -c "SELECT oid, datname FROM pg_database;"
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Server 2012, the command `pg_config` did not reveal the data directory for some crazy reason.  But I found it by looking at the file `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\pg_env.bat`, which contained this line:

```
@SET PGDATA=E:\POSTGRESQL
```

That was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X 10.8 and 10.9 (not 10.10) with server app installed, in a terminal window, type

```
sudo serveradmin settings postgres
```

On OS X 10.9 Mavericks, this is the output I get from that, which includes the data directory.

```
postgres:log_connections = "on"
postgres:unix_socket_directory = "/private/var/pgsql_socket"
postgres:listen_addresses = "127.0.0.1,::1"
postgres:unix_socket_group = "_postgres"
postgres:log_statement = "ddl"
postgres:log_line_prefix = "%t "
postgres:unix_socket_permissions = "0770"
postgres:log_lock_waits = "on"
postgres:logging_collector = "on"
postgres:log_filename = "PostgreSQL.log"
postgres:dataDir = "/Library/Server/PostgreSQL/Data"
postgres:log_directory = "/Library/Logs/PostgreSQL"
```

I just tried this in Yosemite (OS X 10.10) and postgres is no longer listed as a service under serveradmin (although postgres is installed).

```
sudo serveradmin list
```

does not list postgres

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, one could also use `ps` to capture the data location such as:

`ps -e |egrep postgres|egrep -E '[[:blank:]]+\-D'| perl -pe 's/^.*[[:blank:]]+-D[[:blank:]]+(\S+).*?$/$1/'`.

This would work most of the time. It would return something like `/usr/local/pgsql/data` or wherever else it was specified in the parameters of PostgreSQL at launch.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the standard utility pg_config such as `pg_config --bindir` One could also get the the configure parameters used to compile PostgreSQL and parse them with `pg_config --configure`

Comment: `--bindir` shows the location of the executables, not the data directory.  `--configure` is OK, even though one has to parse the output a bit.

Comment: Yes that is true and unfortunately pg_config has no parameter that would reveal the datadir. When I wrote this, I thought that at least it gives something close, assuming the datadir is not in a special location. datadir would be relative then to the bindir such as ../data

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @Matthew Mark Miller, on macOS 10.14 using Postgres 11 it is located at:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora and probably several other Linux distros you can change to the postgres user and read the `PGDATA` environment variable. E.g.:

```
sudo su - postgres
echo ${PGDATA}
/var/lib/pgsql/12/data
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are three different libraries in Mac, developers are usually confused with the three scenarios. However, you can find out your PostgreSQL directory with one of the two methods on the Mac Computer.

**1. Directory--Absolute Path**

1). Scroll up your mouse to the left top of Mac Screen

2). Click the menu "Go"

3). Select the "Go to Folder..."

4). Input the path

/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Postgres

Please change "username" to your name such as "jack" listed as follows.

/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Postgres

5). Choose the button "Go" to the directory of Postgres.

You will eventually find out Postgres.

**2. Find the directory step by step**

1). Scroll up your mouse to the left top of Mac Screen.

2). Click the menu "Go".

3). Select the button "Library"

4). Double click the file holder "Application Support".

5). Find out "Postgres" according to the alphabetic order.

Cheers,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

For M1 Macs with Postgres installed via Homebew, try:

```
/opt/homebrew/var/[postgresql@12 or other version]
```

Answer (score -1):

on macOS Big Sur
version 11.5.2

postgresql 10.17 installed with homebrew
`/opt/pgdata`