# Create database on new partition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I use postgresql 9.1, on ubuntu 12.04. I had installed the depot package.

I have added a new partition to my system, and I would like to create a postgresql database on this partition ( which will be entirely dedicated to this database).

My pgdata is located in `var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main`. I plan to stop the postgresql service, copy the pgdata content to the new partition, then make a symbolic link to the new partition, `chown` the new directory to postgres user, restart postgresql... but I'm afraid this all looks more like a hack.

Is there a way to create a database specifically on a specified partition ? Something more "canonical" (not a play of word with ubuntu)

Comment: It depends on your operating system and whether it's a self-compiled or pre-packaged postgres install, you need to provide these details in the question

Comment: @DanielVérité ubuntu 12.04., ubuntu depot package installed

Comment: Check the answers to this [question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/how-do-i-find-postgresqls-data-directory).

Comment: ok I found it @ var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main

Comment: You don't need the symbolic link, just change the configuration of the postmaster startup script to point to the new data directory. You could also create a tablespace on the new partition and create the new database in that. No need to mess around with the data directory.

Comment: reading postgres doc about create tablespace. it seems to be the canonical thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[CREATE TABLESPACE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtablespace.html) could be used.

```
create tablespace dedicated_datastore owner postgres location '/my/mount/point/'
```

and now the tablespace can be used as parameter when creating a database, (or a table, or an index)

```
create database my_database tablespace dedicated_datastore
```

Comment: I'm not sure about using the phrase **should be used**!! If you only have one database (and/or cluster) then it might be better to use either mount points, symlinks, or change the PGDATA location (in order of preference from various guides). Tablespaces have lots of caveats when it comes to backing up where as having the whole data directory mapped does not.

Comment: @AdamGent noticed your comment only today. I changed it to "could"/