# How to change the data directory on Postgresql 9.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am having a problem changing the data directory on postgresql 9.1 on ubuntu 13.04:

I first did a:

```
sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 9.1 main
```

and then attempted to create a new one in the desired path:

```
 sudo pg_createcluster -d /home/fccoelho/Documentos/databases/postgresqldata 9.1 main
```

but i fails with a permission denied:

```
Creating new cluster (configuration: /etc/postgresql/9.1/main, data: /home/fccoelho/Documentos/databases/postgresqldata/)...
initdb: could not access directory "/home/fccoelho/Documentos/databases/postgresqldata": Permission denied
Error: initdb failed
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

If you create a cluster in Debian/Ubuntu without specifying the owner (option `--user` of `pg_createcluster`) then you have to be sure that the directory you specify is accessibile in r/w to the `postgres` user. Please note that all parent directories should also be accessibile to the same user with bit `x` (list directory content).

Otherwise, you may specify a different owner using option `--user`. This should create a cluster ran by that user instead of `postgres`.

In order to check if postgres user may access that directory, execute this command:

```
sudo su - postgres -c 'touch /home/fccoelho/Documentos/databases/postgresqldata/test'
```

and check for any error.

Comment: To further this comment the user needs to have read and execute access to all the directories upto this specific directory and the user need r+w access to data directory.

Comment: Hi @GaneshKrishnan, I tried with only bit "x" on all parent directories and that worked. Did you find a different behaviour? Is bit "r" really compulsory for all parent directories?

Comment: I suppose x should suffice but I erred on the side of caution. As long as the user can list the contents of the directory. he is good to go.

Answer (score 1):

When I wanted to switch my databases to another drive (with more space), and ask the question here: [Create database on new partition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37013/create-database-on-new-partition) , the answer was:

```
create tablespace dedicated_datastore owner postgres location '/my/mount/point/'
```

With it you can create database at the place you want. Just indicate the tablespace to use at creation. And you can of course have several tablespaces pointing at different mount points (and harddrive) if ever needed.

Answer (score 0):

The data directory should be [owned by the `postgres` user](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/postgres-user.html):

> [postgres] user account should only own the data that is managed by the server

So you have to issue a command like

```
chown -R postgres:postgres /home/fccoelho/Documentos/databases/postgresqldata
```

first, then try to create the cluster.

Comment: I have tried that to no avail:
$ ll /home/fccoelho/Documentos/databases/postgresqldata
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres  0 Abr 15 08:52 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 fccoelho fccoelho 62 Abr 15 08:52 ../

Comment: Are you logged in with the `postgres` user?

Comment: I think this happens because of rights in parent directories. Please have a look at my complete answer.

Comment: @eppesuig Might be completely true, I tried to set up the data dir directly in the users home, which has that access by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, but not really the solution:

I found out I cannot maintain the data directory within my home tree so I created a new directory `/home/postgresqldata/` and ran:

```
sudo pg_createcluster -d /home/postgresqldata/ 9.1 main
```

Everything worked as expected!!

Comment: I tested this on my machine and I could run `initdb` on a directory in a user's home without problem.

Comment: I think this happend because of rights in parent directories. Please have a look at my complete answer.