# Difference between total table size and size of all pages in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, disk-space, size, dimension

Working with Postgres I noticed the following:

When I run this query I get the total table size:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_table_size('tenk1') );
```

I get 384kb.

And when I run:

```
SELECT relpages FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'tenk1';
```

I get 45 pages. I know that one page has 8kb. I confirmed that with `SELECT current_setting('block_size');`

Therefore, my table size should be 45 * 8kB = 360kB, instead of 384kb.
Where does the difference of 24kb come from?

What else could take up this space? I know that indexes are excluded by `pg_table_size`.
But its TOAST table if any, free space map, and visibility map are included. Is there a way to determine their sizes?

Comment: Go here [System admin functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) and look at entry for `pg_relation_size()`.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`pg_table_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) includes auxiliary relations (TOAST table, free space map, visibility map).

The number in `pg_class.relpages` should correspond to the result of [`pg_relation_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE), which only includes the "main" relation (unless instructed otherwise with a 2nd parameter).

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('tenk1'));
```

But keep in mind that [`pg_class.relpages`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) ...

> ... is only an estimate used by the planner. It is updated by `VACUUM`, `ANALYZE`, and a few DDL commands such as `CREATE INDEX`.

That includes autovacuum. But it's not always up to date after recent write activity.

---

> TOAST table ... free space map, and visibility map ... Is there a way to determine their sizes?

```
SELECT pg_relation_size(oid, 'fsm')    AS free_space_map
     , pg_relation_size(oid, 'vm')     AS visibility_map
     , pg_table_size(reltoastrelid)    AS toast_size_incl_vm_fsm
     , pg_relation_size(reltoastrelid) AS toast_size_main
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  oid = 'tenk1'::regclass;
```

TOAST tables have their own, separate free space map and visibility map. `toast_size_incl_vm_fsm` shows the total TOAST size including these relation forks, and `toast_size_main` shows the size of the main TOAST relation.

See:

- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)

You can double-check by looking at actual files in the DB directory. See:

- [How do I find PostgreSQL's data directory?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/how-do-i-find-postgresqls-data-directory/246627)

Each DB has its own subdirectory by the name of the database OID. It contains files representing all the above relation forks, named after the corresponding OID in `pg_class`.